# Why my JSON file is showing all the values in a single key?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I had scrapped a website using Node.js environment. I had parsed the data in JSON format and saved the JSON data in a file named output.js

But instead of creating different keys (with different arrays) for different values, the whole data (value) gets stored in a single key. I had used "each" function and formed a loop to stored them in the different arrays but that seems like not working.

What may be the possible glitch?

Here is the code:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var fs      = require('fs');

var allJSONdata = [];

 request ('http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.aspx',
  function (error, response, html) {
     if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
     var allRecords = $('div.content');

     allRecords.each(function(index, element){ 
     var title = $(element).find('td.TTHeadergrey').text();

     var tempData = {
         Header:title
        }
     allJSONdata.push(tempData);
     });

   }
  fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(allJSONdata), function(err){  
    console.log('successfully saved');
})
});
```

And my output.json data is following:

```
[{"Header":" /*all heads in this single key*/ "}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right selectors, so... Change this:

```
     var allRecords = $('div.content');

     allRecords.each(function(index, element){ 
     var title = $(element).find('td.TTHeadergrey').text();

     var tempData = {
         Header:title
        }
     allJSONdata.push(tempData);
     });
```

to this:

```
var allRecords = $('.content .TTHeadergrey');


allRecords.each(function(index, element){
    if( (index % 5)===0 ||  (index % 5)===1){
        var title = $(element).text();
        var tempData = {
            Header:title
        };
        allJSONdata.push(tempData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! it worked. Why is the selector not right in my code?

Comment: $('div.content') get the div that 'holder' all others "headers", so when you call find('td.TTHeadergrey'), it will return all titles instead of only one as you want.

Comment: One more ques. How can I fetch only every first and fifth ..TTHeadergrey from the source website. 1st & 5th then 6th & 10th then 11th & 15th... so on. And then stored them in diff keys like title & body. I tried the way you examined the code above but didn't worked.